# Redirect if subfolder is not present in url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm looking to create a redirect if url begins with /folder but does not contain /folder/subfolder

Eg:

```
/folder/page
```

Should redirect to:

```
/folder/subfolder/page
```

I've tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/subfolder/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/subfolder/$1 [L]
```

But that doesn't work. It needs to be a general redirect as I have many pages to redirect. It should be possible, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your .htaccess in following manner. There were 2 primarily things needed to be corrected in your nice attempts. 1st: You need not to match path after `subfolder` in condition part. 2nd: you are capturing everything including `folder` in rewrite part which we don't need since on right side you are already mentioning it.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Following will not **redirect** URL in browser its an internal rewrite based on your attempts.

```bash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/?folder/subfolder/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)/?$ /folder/subfolder/$1 [NC,L]
```

***OR*** In case you want a real redirect and **change URL** on browser level then try following:

```bash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/?folder/subfolder/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)/?$ /folder/subfolder/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Wow - that was quick. Thank you so much. Your last example was just what I needed!

Comment: I will. Can I bug you with a related question? If I want to go the "other" way around, say I have a url like: folder/folder/unwanted/page where I want it to redirect to /folder/folder/page - would the same principle apply?

Comment: @Dyvel, yes its condition will be changed a bit as per your new path IMHO.